# How to echo string while waiting for variable assignment from another command?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using CLI in which some commands can take few minutes. After it is run, it echos 'in progress' every 10 seconds, until it's done.
Example command:

```
cli run:command --json
```

Example output:

```
in progress
in progress
in progress
{"status":"0", "result":"very good"}
```

I need to assign output json to variable. I do it like this:

```
var=$(cli run:command --json)
```

My output is good, it contains only json, without 'in progress' lines. But  when I'm waiting for command to be done I don't see 'in progress' status every 10 seconds.

How I can assign output to variable, but still see 'in progress' status when I'm waiting for it?

Comment: What's inside `var` then?

Comment: The program could write the progress messages to standard error or `/dev/tty`, otherwise they'll be included in the variable assignment.

Comment: @Fravadona `var` has exactly what I expect - only json part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one method: launch an infinite loop to print 'in progress' *in the background*, and when the "important" command completes, kill the background process:

```sh
(while true; do echo in progress; sleep 1; done) & 
bgpid=$!

var=$(sleep 10; echo done)     # this is your long-running command

kill $bgpid
```